# How to fetch the data from in memory of Express?

Tags: javascript, express, swagger

Hello I am trying to mock the API using swagger and express, in which I require data stored from the in memory database.

Following is my code, by which I am not able to get the data and it gives me syntax error.

I am using petstore application for [mock](https://github.com/BigstickCarpet/swagger-express-middleware/blob/master/samples/sample2.js).

Following is the script I modified as per my need.

What is wrong with the script.?

```
 app.get('/pets', function(req, res, next) {
         var myDB = new MemoryDataStore();
        myDB.get('/pets',function(err, res){

        });
    });
```

Comment: Can you please post the more code including the imports/requires? Also I don't see how you will get any kind of help without actually posting the syntax error.

Comment: You can find the code here - https://github.com/BigstickCarpet/swagger-express-middleware/blob/master/samples/sample2.js, I just need to add one method which fetches the data while we perform get on /pets  -